# Custom Component - Get Application ActiveControl name

Tags: delphi

Hi I have a custom component with 2 Tedit boxes in a panel. When the focus leaves one edit it should set focus on the other edit unless a certain external component(s) has focus. This is straightforward as a VCL app:

```
    unit dem;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StrUtils, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure Edit2Exit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if AnsiContainsStr(Memo1.Text, Screen.ActiveControl.Name) = True then Exit
  else Edit2.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.SetFocus;
end;
end.
```

This switches the focus (on exit) between the 2 edit boxes unless Button2 is clicked.
In my component (I have substituted TStrings(TStringlist) for Memo1 and the TEdits are actually TDBEdits. I need a way to get the application's activecontrol name so I can utilitise the above code. Obviously `Screen.ActiveControl.Name` does not work but what will? I would be grateful for any help.

Windows 11, delphi 7

**Edit**

In respect of Andreas Rejbrand’s and Remy Lebeau’s concerns about using `OnExit` I have rethought this and decided that this component is     pointless. I can use something like this to solve the tabbing part

```
    unit dem;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, StrUtils, StdCtrls, TypInfo, ExtCtrls;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Panel1: TPanel;
        Edit1: TEdit;
        Edit2: TEdit;
        Memo1: TMemo;
    EnterData: TButton;
        Button2: TButton;
        Button3: TButton;
    procedure EnterDataClick(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure ToggleTab(ACont:TWinControl;yorn:Boolean);
    var
      x:Integer;
    procedure HasTextProp(AControl: TControl; yorn:boolean);
    begin
      if IsPublishedProp(AControl, 'TabStop') = True then (AControl as TWinControl).TabStop := yorn;
    end;
    begin
         for x:=0 to ACont.ControlCount-1 do
        begin
          HasTextProp(ACont.Controls[x],yorn);
        end;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.EnterDataClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      ToggleTab(Form1,False);
      Edit1.TabStop:=True;
      Edit2.TabStop:= True;
      Edit1.SetFocus;
    end;

    end.
```

And then using `OnActiveControlChange` to manage the flow.  I am sorry to have wasted all of your times but I did learn NOT to use `OnExit` in this way so thank you for that.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to change focus in an `OnExit` handler.

Comment: Thank you but I need to keep the focus between these 2 boxes as it is part of data input. How could I manage that without OnExit

Comment: Sorry that probably should be another question I will research that but that is not the main question

Comment: Why comparing names if you could compare the controls directly? `if Screen.ActiveControl= Edit1 then`

Comment: I would simply disable everything, that should not get focus.

Comment: Doing focus-changing actions inside of a focus-change event is a recipe for disaster. Windows does not like that at all.  At the very least, your `OnExit` handler should use `TThread.ForceQueue()` or equivalent to delay your intended focus change until after default focus has changed and flow has returned to the message loop.